# Built Variational Autoencoder using Keras in R and Shiny

Tags: r, tensorflow, shiny, keras

I built a Variational Autoencoder using Keras in R,
I noticed that if I train the model on regular R session all work great,
but when I train the model on Shiny session it goes terribly wrong:
When Shiny session gets to the line which train the model:

```
history<- vae %>% fit(
              x_train, x_train, 
              shuffle = TRUE, 
              epochs = 25, 
              batch_size = batch_size, 
              validation_data = list(x_test, x_test)
              )
```

there is no feedback on epoch and the all computer get stuck.
(I don't get any errors just crushing computer)

Is there special configuration to set when using Keras on Shiny?

Edit:
I use the Variational Autoencoder for dimensionality reduction,
here is my function, I use it from shiny server:

```
get_variational_autoencoder<- function(data_set,
                                   reduce_to = 2){
  library(keras)
  use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")

  # Data preparation ---------------------------------
  row_names<- row.names(data_set)
  data_set<- normalize(data_set)
  row.names(data_set)<- row_names

  partition<- data_partition(data_set, .80)
  x_train <- partition["train_set"]$train_set
  x_test <- partition["test_set"]$test_set

  # Parameters ---------------------------------------

  batch_size = DEAFULT_BATCH_SIZE_FOR_AUTOANCODER
  original_dim = dim(data_set)[2]
  latent_dim = reduce_to
  intermediate_dim = (2/3)*original_dim + latent_dim
  nb_epoch = DEAFULT_NUMBER_OF_EPOCH_FOR_AUTOANCODER
  epsilon_std = DEAFULT_EPSILON_FOR_AUTOANCODER

  #encoder
  # input layer
  x <- layer_input(shape = c(original_dim))
  # hidden intermediate, lower-res
  h <- layer_dense(x, intermediate_dim, activation = "relu")
  # latent var 1, 2-dim (mainly for plotting!): mean
  z_mean <- layer_dense(h, latent_dim)
  # latent var 2, 2-dim: variance
  z_log_var <- layer_dense(h, latent_dim)

  sampling <- function(arg){
    z_mean <- arg[, 1:(latent_dim)]
    z_log_var <- arg[, (latent_dim + 1):(2 * latent_dim)]

    epsilon <- k_random_normal(
      shape = c(k_shape(z_mean)[[1]]), 
      mean=0.,
      stddev=epsilon_std
    )

    z_mean + k_exp(z_log_var/2)*epsilon
 }

  z <- layer_concatenate(list(z_mean, z_log_var)) %>% 
   layer_lambda(sampling)

  # hidden intermediate, higher-res
  decoder_h <- layer_dense(units = intermediate_dim, activation = "relu")
  # decoder for the mean, high-res again
  decoder_mean <- layer_dense(units = original_dim, activation = "sigmoid")
  h_decoded <- decoder_h(z)
  x_decoded_mean <- decoder_mean(h_decoded)

  # the complete model, from input to decoded output
  vae <- keras_model(x, x_decoded_mean)

  # encoder, from inputs to latent space
  encoder <- keras_model(x, z_mean)

  # generator, from latent space to reconstructed inputs
  decoder_input <- layer_input(shape = latent_dim)
  h_decoded_2 <- decoder_h(decoder_input)
  x_decoded_mean_2 <- decoder_mean(h_decoded_2)
  generator <- keras_model(decoder_input, x_decoded_mean_2)


 vae_loss <- function(x, x_decoded_mean){
    xent_loss <- (original_dim/1.0)*loss_binary_crossentropy(x, 
      x_decoded_mean)
    kl_loss <- -0.5*k_mean(1 + z_log_var - k_square(z_mean) - 
    k_exp(z_log_var), axis = -1L)
    xent_loss + kl_loss
 }

  vae %>% compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = vae_loss, metrics = 
      c('accuracy'))

  # Model training ---------------------------------------------------------

  history<- vae %>% fit(
              x_train, x_train, 
              shuffle = TRUE, 
              epochs = 25, 
              batch_size = batch_size, 
              validation_data = list(x_test, x_test)
              )

  data_set_after_vae <- keras::predict(encoder, data_set, batch_size = 
batch_size)

  vae_result<- list ("v_autoencoder" = vae,
                 "data_set_after_vae" = data_set_after_vae %>% 
                   as_data_frame(),
                 "history" = history,
                 "encoder" = encoder)
  return (vae_result)
}
```

Comment: I use Keras in my shiny apps and it works well. Could you provide a reproducible example so we can help you?

Comment: I add code example, thanks